# PostgreSQL JSON query returns NULL

Tags: json, postgresql, unity-game-engine

I've imported a raw data export from Unity into PostgreSQL using the JSON file that Unity offers.

Sample of data:

```
{"name":"EVENT1","ts":1534117312648,"userid":"1e77723b38980460ea307db5fca875fd","sessionid":"3188654687037448331","platform":"AndroidPlayer","sdk_ver":"u2017.4.1f1","debug_device":false,"user_agent":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; LG-H820 Build/NRD90U)","submit_time":1534118874283,"custom_params":{"the Daily Bonus":"RewardGems"},"country":"US","city":"Fayetteville","appid":"50d97d88-096c-4a4b-8daa-390e239974f8","type":"custom"}
{"name":"GAME1","ts":1534107814910,"userid":"f029c3982539e4eeea171132bd9cf8c9","sessionid":"220388644753439310","platform":"AndroidPlayer","sdk_ver":"u2017.4.1f1","debug_device":false,"user_agent":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-G570M Build/NRD90M)","submit_time":1534118931705,"custom_params":{"Heavy Slam":"1","Flame Breath":"1","Cure":"1","Chop":"1","Bite":"7","Fang Fireball":"10","Axe Throw":"2"},"country":"BR","city":"Várzea Grande","appid":"50d97d88-096c-4a4b-8daa-390e239974f8","type":"custom"}
```

The JSON data is in the `values` column in the `temp_json` table as a text data type. When trying to CAST the column as a JSON datatype I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Character with value 0x0a must be escaped.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...tric Jacket":"1","Bolt":"5","Axe Throw":"1","Toss
SQL state: 22P02
```

As a result I've had to use `to_json(values)`to convert the text column into JSON. When I attempt to run the following query:

```
SELECT to_json(values) -> 'name'
FROM temp_json
```

My query results in NULL. I've searched around and found an answer that stated to try the following query:

```
select json_array_elements(to_json(values)) ->> 'name'
from temp_json
```

Although that results in the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar
SQL state: 22023
```

I'm extremely new to JSON and PostgreSQL so apologies for the noob question. Any help would be very much appreciated. I feel like this should be an easy thing to figure out, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return the "name" parameter from the JSON string you could use the JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT function. See docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

Here is an example of how to use it assuming the JSON string is in the values column in the temp_json table:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(values, 'name') AS name
FROM temp_json;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. When I attempt your suggestion I get the an error stating that the function does not exist. When attempting with `to_json(values)` included in your query I still get the same NULL results. 

The strange thing is when I manually add values from the JSON file into its own separate table...your query and the queries I already used work just fine. However, if I import the file's data using COPY into a table then the same queries return NULL values.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing that error to be honest. Please try to cast the values field as json as follows:
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(values::json , 'name') AS name
    FROM temp_json;

Comment: I get the following error: 

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Character with value 0x0a must be escaped.

Comment: I think you may need to use to_json to escape special characters. This would make the query something like this:

    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(to_json(values), 'name') AS name
    FROM temp_json;

Comment: That also didn't work. The query results in NULL values. Maybe I'll have to figure out an alternative for this.